# Extending generic function parameter type - Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I have just recently started to play around with advanced types and generics in Typescript so please excuse if my formulation is not entirely correct - at least I hope the title makes sense.

**UPDATE** -> I have added a full code example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsFNQc2gO2gJwJYGNQHsBGAraDcCATwAdoAocC2ABQEMVGBbAHgBUA%20UAXlABvUAG0A1tFKg0iUBNLYAZqE4BdAFwrxk1aAC%20VKiAgx4SVJlABHAK6optSjTqgAinZSlOddvX6hGRFIAGlAAJX9A0l4BQSpQUHJmNgBnTSYWDnpueNAUaBTybEQU6HSUbFY0UvYwnIMjMChYBGR0LFt7MidHWHd7X0ig0IiBKJjQXISuUGgAD3AkABMUtw8vH3pguu4ACkTk1jTQekwxLlCAciTMlMvuEWvDu90ASn5eU4xzziv8wuKpXuj3%20RRK0EuqkMxma0kQ5BsJBubGgixQKSoMjRikYGFgAEl4YihFMDpkAIyaFLgdCIOCk5GsABMmkQNlYuFQDMOAGZNLhsNgADbQQJUBrGAC00plsrl8pljVAADF8WEAMqcUAAYQAguqAKJKhUm03OShrezqyqoyAyOD%20fqebyUdiEhHgULU2lwHJUDBCxgpVauckkhIJcjoABujEW1nWlMtngA3IYI6AMICaTZiNgUPtOp4k06pO84hmM1BqgA6IukMMCevktMZhoZhG4IWWIOkRAddbW1i2%2037GQezTu4mvcqVarQdje%2028CuVhJZkokf6RADujDQJGrKTrifYpaHI7pezhHtAr1ba7yqJsKFk-wfCT0kwlYFNf7lSqGtqADyAByAAiOr6kaUr-nB0JgPimbYDYQpLE%20O7oPGR6hLgxJITuKFoaA3YSBA2CzAsyygAABqWNGgCkNqQNgO7mn06xMoMYzDOEQzRP4pIzPMiyICsyYbK6Ww7IW6xUjS9qhIyxxfD8VzKcCTy3JCd4fCcZwXKAlygoCEIPMZBRgkCUL%20oGwZuEy4YRlGaCxvG9YshJTJpqSG7erm4D5rJ9glpxumrmuR4nvYjlNomH76Omzk2F2PYpH2A5Wja1Z0sFnjyT6oTjoik5EiQM4nBUVQ1EuV5OWuflbgUu77oedrHh5Z6DtldpXnlIQ3tOCUZvk4Avm%20BQJV%204q5EAA)

##### What I want to do

Assume two (query) functions, where one takes only an **object** as parameter and the other one takes a **query string** and an object as parameter.

```js
// only object
const query1 = ({ ...params }) => { return ...; }

// query AND object
const query2 = (query, { ...params }) => { return ...; }
```

Both functions are contained in separate classes where they also get typed

```js
class Q1 {
  private query1: Query1;

  ...
}

class Q2 {
  private query2: Query2;

  ...
}
```

##### Type definitions

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is that **both function types** derive from a single generic type. What I have so far is

```js
// the generic object type --> I guess here I would need to define it differently
type Param<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] }

// the generic query type which contains `params` and `response` types
type QueryType<P = any, R = any> = {
  params: Param<P>
  response: Promise<R>
}

// the generic function type for my queries
type Query<P = any, R = any> = 
  <T extends QueryType<P,R>>( params: Pick<T, 'params'>['params'] ) => Pick<T, 'response'>['response']
```

For the first case `query1()` I do not really need to exend anything. I only need to apply the *param* and *response types*, eg

```js
interface Input {
 param1: string,
 param2: number,
 param3: boolean
}
type QuerySomething = QueryType<Input, string>

class Q1 {
  private query1: Query;

  // just for completeness - I do not wanna type out `query1` here
  constructor( query1: Query ) {
    this.query1 = query1;
  }

  // and I would use this somehow like
  public async querySomething(input: Input): Promise<string> {
    const res = await this.query1<QuerySomething>( input );
    return res;
  } 
}
```

For the second case I simply can't figure out how to extend `type Query` that it will accept a parameter `query: string` in addition to the params object, without rewriting `type Query`. So

```js
interface Input {
 param1: string,
 param2: number,
 param3: boolean
}

// I guess I have to do something here?
type QuerySomething = QueryType<Input, string>

class Q2 {
  private query2: Query;

  ...

  public async querySomething(query: string, params: Input): Promise<string> {
    const res = await this.query2<QuerySomething>( query, params );
    return res;
  } 
}
```

What I could do of course

```js
type Query2<P = any, R = any> = 
  <T extends QueryType<P,R>>( query:string, params: Pick<T, 'params'>['params'] ) => Pick<T, 'response'>['response']
```

I hope this makes sense! I am still really confused with Typescript and I apologise if this is complete nonsense here!

Thanks!

Comment: what is the relationship between the call signature of `querySomething` and the query itself? you've shown them to be identical so I think the generics could simplify a lot here `class Q<T>{ query2: T;   public querySomething: T = async (...)=> {...}}` but I'm not sure how much of an example vs real case that is. ( I want to clarify this before I post an answer that doesn't help your real case)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, I do not understand your suggestion. Is the call signature of `querySomething` in `Q1` and `Q2` not different since in the first case I only pass `input: Input` and in the second case I do `query: string, params: Input`?

Comment: yes they are different but are they always the same as the `query` object that is passed to each respective constructor? (or at least the same as the field `query1` and `query2`

Comment: The minified example pretty much resembles my real case scenario. I think I know what you mean but would this already solve my problem?  I have also posted the link to `typesriptlang.org` for the full example in my answer. Maybe this helps

Comment: after looking at your full example again I think adding generics to the call signatures is a red herring (like your `Query2` both takes generics and returns a generic function, the generic function is not what you want), since within the class the type should be well established it just means you are asserting the types in a really roundabout way. I also want to ask, is the eventual goal to combine the `Q1` and `Q2` classes? I wrote my answer assuming not but I'm now wondering if you just want to make `Q_base` your actual implementation

Comment: Ok. I thought that I'm on the wrong track here. The main goal is not to combine the two classes. The 2 functions `query1` and `query2` resemble fetch queries I get from a custom lambda function. They basically do the same but have different call signatures. So is my approach totally wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238946/discussion-between-tadhg-mcdonald-jensen-and-florian-ragossnig).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying out multiple different approaches over the last couple of days I have a (kind of) satisfying solution for my problem. I wan't to thank [@Tadhg McDonald-Jensen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5827215/tadhg-mcdonald-jensen) for taking time and pushing me into the right direction!

So, I have changed and simplified the **generic type definitions**

```
// the generic object type
type Param<T> = { [key in keyof T]: T[key] }

// the generic query type
type QueryType<P, R> = {
  params: Param<P>
  response: Promise<R>
}

// generic typecast 
type TypeCast<T> = Param<T>[keyof T]

// the generic query type
type Query<P = any, R = any> = 
    <T extends QueryType<P, R>>( ...args: TypeCast<T['params']>[] ) => T['response']
```

While type `Param` and `QueryType` remain the same `Query` has changed to accept **multiple arguments** and I have added an additional type `TypeCast`, which simply returns the type of the parameter. So if we go back to the original example we would get

```
// the input parameters
interface Input {
  param1: string
  param2: number
  param3: boolean
}

// the type which we want to apply to the query function
type QuerySomething = QueryType<{ query: string, input: Input }, string>

// testing
type test = TypeCast<QuerySomething['params']>

// resolves to type test = string | Input
```

Applying this to the **query function** will give the desired results

> <sup>I probably should mention, that my initial idea was not to have the same class method names `querySomething` in each class. This methods just represent a superset of many different class methods. The distinction between the 2 classes has been implemented since, `query1` represents the fetch method from *one* external API endpoint and `query2` another API endpoint.</sup>

```
type QuerySomething = QueryType<{ input: Input }, string>
type QuerySomethingElse = QueryType<{ query: string, input: Input }, string>

class Q {
  // just for simplification, these methods would be in different classes
  private query1: Query;
  private query2: Query;

  constructor( query1: Query ) {
    this.query1 = query1;
    this.query2 = query2;  
  }

  public async querySomething( query: string, input: Input ): Promise<string> {
    const res = await this.query1<QuerySomething>( input );
    return res;
  }

  public async querySomethingElse( query: string, input: Input ): Promise<string> {
    const res = await this.query2<QuerySomethingElse>( query, input );
    return res;
  } 
}
```

This will resolve to

```
// Typechecks
const res = await this.query1<QuerySomething>( input );            // OK
const res = await this.query1<QuerySomething>( query );            // ERROR -> OK

const res = await this.query2<QuerySomethingElse>( query, input ); // OK
const res = await this.query2<QuerySomethingElse>( input, query ); // ERROR -> OK

// Argument checks
const res = await this.query1<QuerySomething>();                   // OK -> should be ERROR
const res = await this.query1<QuerySomething>( input, input );     // OK -> should be ERROR

const res = await this.query2<QuerySomethingElse>( query, input, query ); // OK -> should be ERROR
const res = await this.query2<QuerySomethingElse>( query, input, input ); // OK -> should be ERROR
```

So basically, it does the right thing but by type definition **does not take care about the number of arguments**. If any of the Typescript wizards knows how to do this, I'd be happy to hear their solution! For now I think this is the best I can do.

If anyone is interested, I have updated the [TS Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBcAsFNQc2gO2gJwJYGNQHsBGAraDcCATwAdoAocC2ABQEMVGBbAHgBUA%20UAXlABvUAG0A1tFKg0iUBNLYAZqE4BdAFwrxk1aAC%20VKiAgx4SVJlABHAK6optSjTqgAinZSlOddvQA0oABKvAKCVKCg5MxsAM6aTCwc9NzhoCjQMeTYiDHQ8SjYrGi57MFUBkZgCMjoWI5EjDEkzpQqdADCjeBcIaAJbD3aCspqhsZQsNUWWLb2ZE71bh6kvvygjIikAYFrG6S9qRFcoNAAHuBIACYxS-belL7b3NwAFKAAdJ-McHFtlJ1NLgiADkUUSMWBqm4Il0AEp%20LxOCD0plsrlIYZKiZYDJyDYSGC2NALigYlQZCTFIwMLAAJKIPEkMIRCKE1gARk0TXQiDgh0i0VYACZNIgbKxcKh%20WyAMyaXDYbAAG2gG3KhkW7nsAGVCsTIDI4GstZ57tB2MJcfjNPTGfoAtzDSlNctdax9YaAKJK3LG5Zmi3WZZc8A8uABK3gG0M-H20CO3kpKgYJWNG6uITS9AAN0YFyD9k5t08AG4s2hc-nZp4RcXSGX%20Rg0aGbMRsCg3tXSEWTVsCzXNL3QPDmSyx1Biu8u%20y1tOy2PxwaYlPlkLZ6v5yyKmO8bglZZGqREDNXXqJ7zO8H46HDRGY1HQLbY7D8oViuaE3BeKOF6AmzkSBRXYAHdGDQEgJ2Xad2F7N0PUTN5h03X90nAGwUFkFFkP0QwdxsPcDxiI8Tx1M8DV5b1ckvewQzDO9GWjRkAlYds8mvMNh1fIoSk-b9%20THf8mjSDIQLAiClxXewhRg093XPOBKOgV5%20z7SN6PxAIu005YkP4llUPQzCMmwvRQHVCIgA)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may help is to take a step back and try to describe a base abstract class that both `Q` classes should implement, you might come up with something like this:

```
abstract class Q_Base {
  public abstract querySomething(...args: any[]): Promise<any>
}
```

However we obviously want the type of arguments and return type to be constrained, we might consider taking a generic that is just the entire call signature of that method:

```
abstract class Q_Base2<Query_signature extends (...args:any[])=>Promise<any>> {
  public abstract querySomething(...args:Parameters<Query_signature>): ReturnType<Query_signature>;
}
interface Q1Input {
  // I assume this is well defined for you
}
class Q1 extends Q_Base2<(input: Q1Input)=>Promise<string>>{
  public async querySomething(input: Q1Input): Promise<string>{
    return ""
  }
}
```

Since this type has to be unwrapped with `Parameters` and `ReturnType` using a single generic for the function type is a little silly (if you were using arrow functions you could use `public abstract querySomething: Query_Signature` but that is up to you) so instead perhaps we could use 2 generics to represent the arguments and return type seperately:

```
abstract class Q_Base3<Params extends any[], R extends Promise<any>> {
  // could also leave no retriction on R and return type Promise<R> depending on which semantics are easier for you
  public abstract querySomething(...args: Params): R
}
class Q1_3 extends Q_Base3<[input: Q1Input], Promise<string>>{
  // this was filled in with the quick fix of Q1_3 does not implement necessary abstract methods
  public querySomething(input: Q1Input): Promise<string> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
  }
}
```

Either of those will likely work for you, but I think the root aid here is the idea that for polymorphism you can define one type that multiple implementations conform to, even with a generic there is some sense that `Q1` and `Q2` have similar behaviour and you can try to capture that in a base class, whether or not you actually use that base class. (it is just as valid to define the generics on Q1 and Q2 respectively)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! There might be a misunderstanding although I will try to play around with this a little bit. The function `querySomething` is not always the same. There are multiple different `querySomething`s which make all use of **one single**  `query1` OR `query2` within the class.